# Accepting user inputs using svDialogs in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have automated an Rmd script that allows the user to change the value for a custom month and year and run a report. I tried using `svDialogs`, but it seems that the inputs aren't popping up when you knit the script. Please see the below code:

```
library(svDialogs)
monthval <- dlg_input(message = "Enter Month (any value from 1 to 12")$res
yearval <- dlg_input(message = "Enter year")$res
period <- paste(yearval, monthval, sep = "-")
```

Is there another hack specifically using `svDialogs`? Thank you